# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'withcolumn'

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

While trying to change the datatype of the column called 'Maxpulse' to an integer, I encountered an `AttributeError`.

My code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace,col
newDF = newDF.withcolumn("Maxpulse",col("Maxpulse").cast(IntegerType()))
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'withcolumn'
```

Comment: What is the type of newDF ?

Comment: Try replacing 'withcolumn' by 'withColumn' and see

Answer (score 0):

If your `newDF` is a pandas dataframe then pandas does not have `withColumn` and you will get error.

---

If your `newDF` is a spark dataframe then do `withColumn`(capital C) as commented by @Priyanka

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace,col
newDF=newDF.withColumn("Maxpulse",col("Maxpulse").cast(IntegerType()))
```